# Block port on Docker containers using iptables

Tags: iptables, docker, docker-compose

I have a service running on port 3007 in Docker, it's set up like this:

```
services:
    api:
        ports:
        - 3007:80
```

I tried adding a rule to the DOCKER-USER chain to block nonlocal traffic on that port:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 3007 ! -s 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

However, this didn't work. Looking at the rules on the DOCKER chain it seems like the forwarded ports are the the ones on the inside of the container (80 and not 3007), so I'm not sure how to go about managing access to them.

Comment: One workaround is to configure the app to run on port 3007 within the container so that the rule matches traffic to it, but I'll leave the question up since I can't do this for all my services

Comment: If you don't want the port to accept outside traffic, why did you expose it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I need to reverse proxy some of the exposed ports, others are communicated with by applications that aren't in containers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the exposed port to the loopback interface.

```yaml
services:
    api:
        ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:3007:80"
```